# Why you can't buy fish on hot days?

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, situation

My personal situation during my first summer job:

> I loved the fish sold by an old man in his little wooden booth, but when the weather was sunny and hot like hell, you were not able to buy the fish.
>   The cook and the fish were both in the booth, you could enter it, and although the fridge and stove were both working, noone could purchase the fish. Why?

Comment: Maybe because on sunny days it is considered to be almost impossible to catch fish, so on the day after the cook would have less product. That's why he saves his products for the days to come.

Comment: So what was the real reason?

Answer (score 12):

> The currency in his village melts in the heat, and the street vender doesn’t accept credit card. But even if you could pay him, it still wouldn’t be possible. Being a superstitious man, the cook refuses to sell fish on hot days, not only because it is considered bad luck in his culture, but because his son died selling fish on a hot day. He uses the time to mourn the loss of his son, and while you are free to enter the booth, you will only find him crying.

Comment: +1 for too real

Comment: +1 This was a rollercoaster ride from start to finish.

Comment: @Riley Can't wait for the movie adaptation

Comment: "...his son died selling fish on a hot day." Now there's a backstory which needs to be told.

Comment: On a summer day many years ago, the fishmonger allowed his son to manage the booth by himself. The son was so eager to gain his father’s approval that he did everything he could to sell the fish. He sold so many fish that his father could not be more proud. The next day, everyone in the village had gotten sick because the fish had been spoiled! The son hadn’t taken proper precautions for storing fish. Ashamed of his great failure, he had no reason to live, and so he took his own life. All these years later, nobody has a desire to buy or sell fish on hot days.

Answer (score 3):

> He is selling live fish and he won't sell them if he thinks they'll overheat and die on the way back to your home.

Answer (score 3):

> He has neither air conditioning nor a summer kitchen, and so, on the very hot days, he refuses to do any cooking. Today, you can buy ice cream. For fish, come back when the heat's not so unbearable.

Answer (score 3):

> Heat causes everyone to use Air Con, [overloading the grid and causing power outages](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-australia-power/heat-wave-leaves-thousands-of-australian-homes-without-power-idUSKBN1FI0CO). The shopkeeper does not accept cash, only electronic payment, which means he cannot take payment and therefore can't make sales.

Comment: How could the fridge be working though?

Answer (score 3):

> You couldn't buy the fish on a hot day because it would be given away free! XD

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation

> On sunny days, there is a very high demand for fish, so you would have to wait in a long line. But you have a summer job and your lunch break only lasts so long. So you cannot purchase the fish because the wait is longer than your lunch break.

Comment: But is says you (not I) were not able to enter the booth.

Comment: Booth was small and you could enter it, so long line is not an explanation.

Comment: Edited question to make it more clear that noone could buy the fish.

Answer (score 2):

> When it got too hot, the cook took a nap.

Comment: Why did he bother leaving his house if he was napping all day?

Comment: I didn't see anything about leaving your house.

Comment: He didn't nap all day.

Comment: The answer is more complicated than just deciding to nap when it's hot. I don't want to spoil the fun :)

Answer (score 2):

> His fridge was broken so he was relying on his stock of frozen fish to keep other food items cold.

Comment: It says the fridge was working...

Comment: @Riley "was"...

Answer (score 2):

> He probably sells his fishes at night.

Answer (score 1):

> As the booth is made of wood so in really hot weather it is likely to catch 
>  fire so the old man don't use stove that day.

OR

> On hot day the old man don't work and he is the one who could sell the fish, the cook is not allowed to sell.